# Diophantine equation with power

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all the integer solutions of:

$2^{n+1} + 41 = m^2$

I am stuck, and I am not sure if I am going on the right path..

adding 8 to both sides:

$2^{n+1} + 41 + 8 = m^2 + 8$
$2^{n+1} + 49 = m^2 + 8$
$2^{n+1} - 8 = m^2 -49$
$2(2^n - 4) = (m+7)(m-7)$

I am not sure on how to keep going, how do I manage to solve this question?
Thank you!

Comment: You should note that there are a couple of small solutions, so there's no point looking for some simple congruence contradiction.

Comment: Looking at the equation $\bmod 8$ provides one solution. $m$ is plainly odd, and all odd squares are $\equiv 1 \bmod 8$. That means $2^{n+1}\ge 8$, because $41\equiv 1 \bmod 8$. One solution is then seen to be $m=7$. I haven't pursued whether there are other solutions.

Comment: I still don't see how to answer this question I got stuck at the middle

Comment: Another couple of small solutions (m,n): (-13,6) and (13, 6).

Comment: @AugustoSanti yes, but how do you prove it, I can also write a program that does this..

Comment: You should notice that $\,n\,$ is a solution if and only if $\,n \equiv 2 \mod 4$.

Comment: @lulu I tried searching for answers to the equation not to find congruence contradiction, can you please help me solve this? I am lost.. Thank you!!

Comment: The relevant reference appears to be a paper by Apery that I have not found online.  The reference is R. Apéry, Sur une équation diophantienne, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. A 251 (1960), 1263-1264 and 1451-1452.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some insight can be gained by looking at the equation $\bmod 40$. Note that for $n\ge 1$, the residues of $2^{n+1} \bmod 40$ are $\{4,8,16,32,24\}$ with $4$ occurring only once and the other values cycling. Since $4$ does not yield a solution ($4+41\ne m^2$), we can ignore its single occurrence. Of course,  $41\equiv 1 \bmod 40$, so we are looking for solutions to $m^2\equiv \{9,17,33,25\} \bmod 40$. No integer squared ends in the digits $3,7$, so we can further eliminate $17,33$ from consideration, leaving us to examine $m^2\equiv \{9,25\} \bmod 40$. From this, we conclude that $m$ ends in one of the digits $\{3,7,5\}$.

Case 1: $m^2\equiv 25 \bmod 40$. Then $2^{n+1}$ must end in the digits $84$. This occurs for $n+1=20k+14$. $n+1=14,34$ do not yield solutions, and for $n+1=54,74,\dots$ I am not able to calculate, so there might be solutions, but I can't say definitely yes or no.

Case 2: $m^2\equiv 9 \bmod 40$. This implies that $2^{n+1}$ ends in the digit $8$, which occurs when $n+1=4k+3$. The readily found solutions for $n+1=3,7$ are $m=7,13$. Up to $n+1=47$, no further solutions are found.

**Added by edit:** OP correctly points out in a comment that $n$ must be even. If $n$ is odd, then $n+1$ is even, $2^{n+1}$ is a square, and by rearranging terms, $41$ can be expressed as the difference between two squares. Since $41$ is prime, it can only be expressed as the difference between two squares in one way: $41^2-40^2=(21+20)(21-20)$. In this complexion, $m=21$, but $20$ is not a power of $2$, so $n$ cannot be odd, hence $n+1$ cannot be even, which is required in Case 1 where $n+1=20k+14$. Thus there are no Case 1 solutions, as OP states.

Comment: but n is always even so it is not possible that m^2 = 25 mod 40 that case 1 is not possible

Comment: So if only case 2 is valid here, then you solved the whole question?  what about where m = 10K + 7 or m= 10K + 3 ??

Comment: @Remember1312 I pondered looking at those cases, which in essence ask what values $K$ might take, but I made no progress. If there are solutions of those forms however, then there will be values of the exponent $n+1$ that correspond to those solutions, and what I found was that up to $47$ (as high as I could conveniently calculate), no such exponents exits. FWIW, there are many fewer cases to look at when focusing on acceptable values of $n+1$ than on acceptable values of $K$.